# Why is init(frame: CGRect) not being called in my custom UIView class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, subclass

I have a subclass of `UIView` called `GradientView` which I'm using in a `UITableViewCell`

`layoutSubviews()` is called, but my `init` method is never called.

```
import UIKit

class GradientView: UIView {

var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame:frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .orange
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.6, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are not instantiating it to make an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` is not usually initialized with `init(frame:)`, it's initialized with either `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` or `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

The first one will be used when you register a class with your table view, and the second one will be used when it's initialized from a storyboard or when you register a xib file with your table view.